# Edittext set for password with phone number input? (android)

Tags: android, android-edittext

How do I get a Edittext with both a phone input and the ability to hide the string. I know that

```
android:inputType="textPassword"
```

hides the string, while

```
android:inputType="phone"
```

brings up a dialpad interface.

How to combine the two?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`android:password` is deprecated, but AFAIK is the only way because `android:inputType="phone|textPassword"` is ignored ...

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/EditText01"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:password="true"
    android:inputType="phone" />
```

Comment: Ah, interesting. I hadn't seen that it's deprecated. Here's the documentation that mentions `inputType` is the way to go (as Roman mentions): http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#password

Comment: As a little addition, for those who wants to do the stuff from the code: 

editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE);
editText.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());

Comment: inputType="numberPassword" is possibly the best option, but it's only available if your app's min SDK is >= 3.0 (Honeycomb)

Answer (score 5):

I believe this is what you want?

```
android:inputType="numberPassword"
```

Edit: At the time of the question (2010) this may have not been in the API, but for contemporary development, it's available.

Answer (score 2):

I have not found an appropriate solution to this problem. dtmilano's accepted solution doesn't fully work. If the EditText is focused in landscape mode where you have the full screen keyboard, the numbers still display in clear text, not masked.

I spent significant time going through the actual TextView code, and the reason this is a problem is that they are explicitly checking the InputType against InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT and, if I recall correctly, TYPE_MASK_CLASS. So if you include any other InputType within those bounds (I think the range used by TYPE_CLASS_TEXT and TYPE_MASK_CLASS is the first byte), then it won't be recognized as a password that needs masking.

I know what I said is pretty confusing. The actual code is a LOT more confusing. I was pretty appalled at the TextView's code to be honest. It's a tangled mess, with hard coded checks everywhere. Horrible coding practice which leads to problems like this.

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be solved without using deprecated `android:password`. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2420181/android-numeric-password-field/4014588#4014588).

Comment: How do you think android:password works? ;) Yes, it is deprecated XML attribute, but what code is executed in runtime when the attribute is presented?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this, but it might be possible to combine the two like so:

```
android:inputType="textPassword|phone"
```

since [`inputType`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:inputType) can take on multiple values.

Comment: It does not work. The EditText is ignoring the textPassword and just setting to phone

Comment: Sorry about that, my answer was just an educated guess without testing.. dtmilano's snippet looks to be the right way to go.