# Android numeric password field

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an EditText field which needs to be a numeric password field. Everything works OK in portrait mode; not in landscape. When the user selects the EditText field, the UI zooms into the field and when I type all the characters are visible.

I need a numeric keyboard also. I tried setting the input type to text password|number.
If I remove "number" option everything works right; otherwise no.

Any suggestions?

Comment: See the Answer : [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15257058/how-to-show-numeric-soft-keyboard-for-password-field-in-android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15257058/how-to-show-numeric-soft-keyboard-for-password-field-in-android)

Answer (score 61):

This problem can be solved without using deprecated `android:password`. Use the following code snippet, but do not reverse the sequence of calls:

```
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.MyEditText);
    editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
    editText.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
```

Comment: Sure, but somehow not as clear as a simple android:password="true". I wonder why they deprecated it.

Comment: Somehow this does not seem to work on 2.3.x . Turning to landscape the passwort is still visible as described by Mar.

Comment: I just found out that `editText.setSingleLine(true);` after the `editText.setTransformationMethod()` causes the dots to stop being shown !!

Answer (score 18):

The simplest solution that I found for a numeric text entry that needed to be hidden (password style) was to use: `android:inputType="numberPassword"`

Full example that worked for me:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@style/MyLargeTextBox"
    android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background_normal"
    android:id="@+id/txtWebServicePIN"
    android:layout_row="3"
    android:layout_column="2"
    android:layout_columnSpan="2"
    android:minWidth="100dp"
    android:maxWidth="100dp"
    android:inputType="numberPassword"
    android:maxLength="6"/>
```

Comment: `numberKeyboard` does not popup the 'only digits' softkeyboard.

Answer (score 6):

To fix the issue where the password is visible in the landscape mode full-screen editor (as Marcus described), you can add the following line to disable the full-screen editor:

```
editText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_NO_EXTRACT_UI);
```

You may also want to change the typeface to monospace to better emulate the text-password behavior:

```
editText.setTypeface(Typeface.MONOSPACE);
```

Comment: Though this doesn't look nice on small devics, it's definitely a way to get the password hidden.

Answer (score 3):

Using the deprecated

```
android:password="true"
```

may solve your problem.

Comment: Indeed, I was about to link to your previous answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2017674/edittext-set-for-password-with-phone-number-input-android/2017791#2017791

Answer (score 1):

Try this in XML & nothing changes in manifest file,

```
<EditText
         android:id="@+id/etPassword"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:inputType="textPassword"
         android:singleLine="true" />
```

Comment: how does this limit to numeric input only?

Answer (score 0):

This how to make input password that has hint which not converted to * !!.

On XML :

```
android:inputType="textPassword"
android:gravity="center"
android:ellipsize="start"
android:hint="Input Password !."
```

thanks to : mango and rjrjr for the insight :D.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
EditText input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input);
input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
```

More info [HERE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html#TYPE_NUMBER_VARIATION_PASSWORD)

Answer (score -2):

I think you should use `android:password="true"` and `android:numeric="integer"`. But as the Android documentation states (in `R.attr.html`, not in the `TextView` docs), these are deprectated and you should use `android:inputType`. inputType takes flag, so you can mix mulitple possibilities. And I think `android:inputType="number | password"` should work for you.

You should specify `android:password="true"` if you want to support older devices too.

Comment: See dtmilano's answer, plus the link I gave to a previous question which covers these points. Unfortunately passing both into `inputType` doesn't work.