# passing data from dialog to dialog's calling activity?

Tags: android

i have an activity which calls a dialog ...in the dialog i'm asking user to enter a password.Now i need  this password in my activity.Is it possible and how ???...Thanks in advance !!!

Answer (score 1):

You could create an activity that is [themed as a Dialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html)

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
```

and then call that activity with `startActivityForResult(...)` as described [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29).

Answer (score 0):

In the `onClick` listener you will be passed the current `Dialog` as one of the method arguments.

So you can do something like `((TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.passwordField)).getText().toString()` in the `onClick` method.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at this discussion [AlertDialog Input Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3011361/alertdialog-input-text) ..

All you need is to call an Intent when appropriate button(positive or negative) is pressed.

See here :

```
Intent intent=new Intent(context,AnotherActivity.class);
 EditText mUserText;
 mUserText = (EditText) textEntryView.findViewById(R.id.txt_password);
 String strpwd = mUserText.getText().toString();

 intent.putExtra("my_password",strpwd);
 startActivity(intent);
```