# android editText

Tags: android

I'm looking for the easiest way (ie without rewritting a keyboard, if possible - maybe using an existing one out there?) to create an editText to input a digit password.

It's not that uncommon, yet I found no flag combination to do that.

Since it's digit only characters, I either want a digit only keyboard (ideally like on the iphone, `4*3=12 keys`, `0-10+del+ok`), or at least a phone-like keyboard, with `()+*` and characters like that, but so that they can't be written in the textEdit.

I don't mind using deprecated flags.

In particular, number|textPassword for inputType doesn't work (characters not hidden), `android:password="true"` `android:inputType="phone"` and `android:numeric="integer"` `android:password="true"` produce the same result, but the hint text disappears and special characters are still allowed.

Thanks.

Comment: Is this perhaps a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119583/how-do-i-show-the-number-keyboard-on-an-edittext-in-android ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that there might be no easy way to achieve that. `android:password="true"` only hides the input text and `inputType="phone"` still allow some special character for dialing although you can make those character do nothing by handling `KeyEvent`.

I was required to do the same thing once, and eventually implemented a custom layout that only rises when the `EditText` gets focused. If you can't find better solution and you don't have too many `EditText` of this type, maybe it is the way to go

Comment: Could you share the code or do you know of an open source code that produces the similar feature ?

Comment: Unfortunately, that piece of code doesn't belong to me. Have you tried this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2420181/android-numeric-password-field/4014588#4014588. If you don't want special character ignore it by handling `KeyEvent`

Answer (score 0):

```
//declarations
AlertDialog keyboardBuilder;
String number;
float myValue;

//building the keyboard
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.keyboard, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.keyboardLayout));
keyboardBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
keyboardBuilder.setView(layout);

//When you your keyboard to appear
keyboardBuilder.show();

//actions of keys
public void kb1(View v) {number += "1"; keyboardBuilder.setTitle(number);}
    public void kb2(View v) {number += "2"; keyboardBuilder.setTitle(number);}
    public void kb3(View v) {number += "3"; keyboardBuilder.setTitle(number);}
    public void kb4(View v) {number += "4"; keyboardBuilder.setTitle(number);}
    public void kb5(View v) {number += "5"; keyboardBuilder.setTitle(number);}
    public void kb6(View v) {number += "6"; keyboardBuilder.setTitle(number);}
    public void kb7(View v) {number += "7"; keyboardBuilder.setTitle(number);}
    public void kb8(View v) {number += "8"; keyboardBuilder.setTitle(number);}
    public void kb9(View v) {number += "9"; keyboardBuilder.setTitle(number);}
    public void kbPoint(View v) {number += "."; keyboardBuilder.setTitle(number);}
    public void kbE(View v) {number += "e"; keyboardBuilder.setTitle(number);}
    public void kbMoins(View v) {number += "-"; keyboardBuilder.setTitle(number);}

    public void kbDelete(View v)
    {
        if (number.length() > 0)
        {
            number = number.substring(0, number.length()-1);
        }
        keyboardBuilder.setTitle(number);
    }

    public void kbSave(View v) 
    {
        try
        {
            myValue = Float.parseFloat(String.valueOf(number)));
            keyboardBuilder.dismiss();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Forbidden value.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }


              android:id="@+id/keyboardLayout"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/keyboardLayout"
                      android:orientation="horizontal"
                      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                      android:gravity="center">
                      <Button android:text="-" android:onClick="kbMoins" android:id="@+id/hideVerticalDocks" android:layout_height="65px" android:layout_width="85px" android:textSize="35px"></Button>
                      <TextView android:id="@+id/espace" android:text="" android:gravity="center" android:textSize="35px" android:layout_height="65px" android:layout_width="85px"> </TextView>
                      <TextView android:id="@+id/espace" android:text="" android:gravity="center" android:textSize="35px" android:layout_height="65px" android:layout_width="85px"> </TextView>
                      <TextView android:id="@+id/espace" android:text="" android:gravity="center" android:textSize="35px" android:layout_height="65px" android:layout_width="85px"> </TextView>
                      <TextView android:id="@+id/espace" android:text="" android:gravity="center" android:textSize="35px" android:layout_height="65px" android:layout_width="85px"> </TextView>
                      <TextView android:id="@+id/espace" android:text="" android:gravity="center" android:textSize="35px" android:layout_height="65px" android:layout_width="85px"> </TextView>
                      <Button android:text="1" android:onClick="kb1" android:id="@+id/hideVerticalDocks" android:layout_height="65px" android:layout_width="85px" android:textSize="35px"></Button>
                      <Button android:text="2" android:onClick="kb2" android:id="@+id/hideVerticalDocks" android:layout_height="65px" android:layout_width="85px" android:textSize="35px"></Button>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/keyboardLayout"
                      android:orientation="horizontal"
                      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                      android:gravity="center">
                      <Button android:text="." android:onClick="kbPoint" android:id="@+id/hideVerticalDocks" android:layout_height="65px" android:layout_width="85px" android:textSize="35px"></Button>
                      <TextView android:id="@+id/espace" android:text="" android:gravity="center" android:textSize="35px" android:layout_height="65px" android:layout_width="85px"> </TextView>
                      <TextView android:id="@+id/espace" android:text="" android:gravity="center" android:textSize="35px" android:layout_height="65px" android:layout_width="85px"> </TextView>
                      <TextView android:id="@+id/espace" android:text="" android:gravity="center" android:textSize="35px" android:layout_height="65px" android:layout_width="85px"> </TextView>
                      <TextView android:id="@+id/espace" android:text="" android:gravity="center" android:textSize="35px" android:layout_height="65px" android:layout_width="85px"> </TextView>
                      <TextView android:id="@+id/espace" android:text="" android:gravity="center" android:textSize="35px" android:layout_height="65px" android:layout_width="85px"> </TextView>
                      <Button android:text="3" android:onClick="kb3" android:id="@+id/hideVerticalDocks" android:layout_height="65px" android:layout_width="85px" android:textSize="35px"></Button>
                      <Button android:text="4" android:onClick="kb4" android:id="@+id/hideVerticalDocks" android:layout_height="65px" android:layout_width="85px" android:textSize="35px"></Button>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/keyboardLayout"
                      android:orientation="horizontal"
                      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                      android:gravity="center">
                      <Button android:text="e" android:onClick="kbE" android:id="@+id/hideVerticalDocks" android:layout_height="65px" android:layout_width="85px" android:textSize="35px"></Button>
                      <TextView android:id="@+id/espace" android:text="" android:gravity="center" android:textSize="35px" android:layout_height="65px" android:layout_width="85px"> </TextView>
                      <TextView android:id="@+id/espace" android:text="" android:gravity="center" android:textSize="35px" android:layout_height="65px" android:layout_width="85px"> </TextView>
                      <TextView android:id="@+id/espace" android:text="" android:gravity="center" android:textSize="35px" android:layout_height="65px" android:layout_width="85px"> </TextView>
                      <TextView android:id="@+id/espace" android:text="" android:gravity="center" android:textSize="35px" android:layout_height="65px" android:layout_width="85px"> </TextView>
                      <TextView android:id="@+id/espace" android:text="" android:gravity="center" android:textSize="35px" android:layout_height="65px" android:layout_width="85px"> </TextView>
                      <Button android:text="5" android:onClick="kb5" android:id="@+id/hideVerticalDocks" android:layout_height="65px" android:layout_width="85px" android:textSize="35px"></Button>
                      <Button android:text="6" android:onClick="kb6" android:id="@+id/hideVerticalDocks" android:layout_height="65px" android:layout_width="85px" android:textSize="35px"></Button>`
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/keyboardLayout"
                      android:orientation="horizontal"
                      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                      android:gravity="center">
                      <Button android:text="delete" android:onClick="kbDelete" android:id="@+id/hideVerticalDocks" android:layout_height="65px" android:layout_width="85px" android:textSize="20px"></Button>
                      <TextView android:id="@+id/espace" android:text="" android:gravity="center" android:textSize="35px" android:layout_height="65px" android:layout_width="85px"> </TextView>
                      <TextView android:id="@+id/espace" android:text="" android:gravity="center" android:textSize="35px" android:layout_height="65px" android:layout_width="85px"> </TextView>
                      <TextView android:id="@+id/espace" android:text="" android:gravity="center" android:textSize="35px" android:layout_height="65px" android:layout_width="85px"> </TextView>
                      <TextView android:id="@+id/espace" android:text="" android:gravity="center" android:textSize="35px" android:layout_height="65px" android:layout_width="85px"> </TextView>
                      <TextView android:id="@+id/espace" android:text="" android:gravity="center" android:textSize="35px" android:layout_height="65px" android:layout_width="85px"> </TextView>
                      <Button android:text="7" android:onClick="kb7" android:id="@+id/hideVerticalDocks" android:layout_height="65px" android:layout_width="85px" android:textSize="35px"></Button>
                      <Button android:text="8" android:onClick="kb8" android:id="@+id/hideVerticalDocks" android:layout_height="65px" android:layout_width="85px" android:textSize="35px"></Button>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/keyboardLayout"
                      android:orientation="horizontal"
                      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                      android:gravity="center">
                      <Button android:text="save" android:onClick="kbSave" android:id="@+id/hideVerticalDocks" android:layout_height="65px" android:layout_width="85px" android:textSize="20px"></Button>
                      <TextView android:id="@+id/espace" android:text="" android:gravity="center" android:textSize="35px" android:layout_height="65px" android:layout_width="85px"> </TextView>
                      <TextView android:id="@+id/espace" android:text="" android:gravity="center" android:textSize="35px" android:layout_height="65px" android:layout_width="85px"> </TextView>
                      <TextView android:id="@+id/espace" android:text="" android:gravity="center" android:textSize="35px" android:layout_height="65px" android:layout_width="85px"> </TextView>
                      <TextView android:id="@+id/espace" android:text="" android:gravity="center" android:textSize="35px" android:layout_height="65px" android:layout_width="85px"> </TextView>
                      <TextView android:id="@+id/espace" android:text="" android:gravity="center" android:textSize="35px" android:layout_height="65px" android:layout_width="85px"> </TextView>
                      <Button android:text="9" android:onClick="kb9" android:id="@+id/hideVerticalDocks" android:layout_height="65px" android:layout_width="85px" android:textSize="35px"></Button>
                      <Button android:text="0" android:onClick="kb0" android:id="@+id/hideVerticalDocks" android:layout_height="65px" android:layout_width="85px" android:textSize="35px"></Button>`
        </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

If you want to hide the password you can delete the keyboardBuilder.setTitle.

The xml was poorly made for a 800*480 landscape, feel free to write it better.

You can also delete the "e", "-" and "." since you just want it for password use.

Note that the checking for not a value with the toast can be deleted, but you can replace it by checking password size for example.

Comment: I tried your snippet but I must be doing something wrong because this is what I get: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/8/keyboardn.png/
Could you please tell in a little more details how to use it ?
Thanks

Comment: As I said it was designed for a 800*480. Try in each of the 5 LinearLayout of the xml to delete 3 out the 5 of : <TextView android:id="@+id/espace" ... You can also play with the width and heigt of each element.

Comment: I tried to reuse your architecture idea but I completely rewrote the layout since it didn't fit my need. I tried using [this code](http://pastebin.com/szmysETj) to make the alertDialog go on the bottom of the screen but it just pops up in the center of it. I'm also not pleased with the fact that there is a white border, nor with the fact that it doesn't take the whole width.