# android popup window

Tags: android

I'm trying to create my own virtual keyboard since no default keyboard fits my needs.
I have created the layout (keyboard.xml), and I'd like to make my keyboard to appear in the bottom of the screen, as other keyboards do. I thought of using popupWindow.
I tried `pw.showAtLocation(this.findViewById(R.id.mainLinearLayout), Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 0)`, where mainLinearLayout is the id of the (root xml element) linearLayout of the currentActivity, but I get a **"android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?"**.
Any idea how to solve that ?

Thanks.

Comment: Try providing various other contexts. This is only bcoz your popup is not recieveing the required context properly

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand your suggestion. Where should I try to provide another context ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a way with an alertDialog. The alertDialog contains your xml.
check my answer here :

[android editText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7108344/android-edittext/7108803#7108803)

And then for positionning your alerDialog see this thread :

[Show AlertDialog in any position of the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5469005/show-alertdialog-in-any-position-of-the-screen)

Comment: This trick for positionning doesn't seem to work for me. See the other thread for my comment.