# How do I specify EditText inputType as number and password?

Tags: android, android-widget

I have the following:

```
<EditText
    android:inputType="number"
    android:password="true"
    ....
</EditText>
```

I'm getting a warning that "android:password" is deprecated and that I should use inputType instead.  Is there a way to specify inputType as number and password?

Comment: see this [question][1] its exactly what you want 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2420181/android-numeric-password-field

Answer (score 47):

Set `android:inputType="numberPassword"`

See this [Link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:inputType)

Comment: I am targeting api 8 (2.2 and above).  It appears numberPassword is not an available option.

Answer (score 18):

you should use [TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html#TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER).

EDIT:

As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2017791/603127)

```
android:inputType="textPassword|number"
```

ignore textPassword and only **accept number** but **not password**.

So you should use `android:inputType="textPassword|number"` with `android:password="true"`.

that seems to be the only solution.

Comment: `android:password="true"` is deprecated. `android:inputType="numberPassword"` will work.

Answer (score 2):

Just set your input type to this **`android:inputType="textPassword|number"`**

Comment: This does not seem to work.  I still have the numeric keyboard, but the user can still see the text.