# Opening only numeric keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard, android-edittext

I want to open only numeric keyboard with input type numeric password. Code is as follows.

```
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/passcode1"
                    android:layout_width="90dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                    android:cursorVisible="false"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                    android:inputType="numberPassword"
                    android:maxLength="4"
                    android:singleLine="true" />
```

Everything working great but Soft Keyboard opens with special symbols and numeric digits. I want only numeric digits must be visible there.

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9880516/how-do-i-specify-edittext-inputtype-as-number-and-password

Comment: @Carnal Thanks but already tried but android:password="true" is depreciated. Is there any alternate method.

Comment: @Carnal There is nothing to afraid :)

Answer (score -2):

Please change
 `android:inputType="numberPassword"` 
to 
 `android:inputType="number|textPassword"`

Comment: keyboard showing only numeric digits but digits are visible not as of type password