# How to combine number and password input tag for Android

Tags: android, cordova, input

I am developing app for android platform with **cordova/phonegap**. I have some form with inputs and I would like to create input tag which will combine password and number type.

type="password" means that text is not visible

type="number" means that android will show up numeric keyboard

Is it possible somehow? I already tried this one:

```
<input type="password" pattern="[0-9]*">
```

This should work for iphone, but it is not working for android (version 4.x).
I guess some javascript code can solve this, but first looking for simple nice solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Android is very different from iPhone.
You cannot program in JavaScript(OK, you can, but few do)!
Instead, we use Java for what iPhone uses JavaScript.

Nevertheless, here is your answerer:
[How do I specify EditText inputType as number and password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9880516/how-do-i-specify-edittext-inputtype-as-number-and-password), and through that:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:inputType.

So, `android:inputType="numberPassword"` should solve your needs.

Comment: Nope, I am using phonegap/cordova framework - html, css, javascript, jquery... No java at all :) But thanks for trying.

Comment: Hi @misoK, have you found the answer for this case? I have the same question.

Comment: Hi @danisupr4 - I did not, I guess it was not possible to do that. I'm not sure if it is possible now.