# EditText input numbers as password style on Android

Tags: android

I am currently developing an App for Android. I am creating an Alert Dialog with input boxes and I need the input boxes to be numbers only but as a password input. How can I do this google isn't finding me anything only one or the other. This needs to be done programatically not using XML

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Edittext set for password with phone number input? (android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2017674/edittext-set-for-password-with-phone-number-input-android)

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/EditText01"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:password="true"
android:inputType="phone" />
```

Comment: I went for the xml in the end as I later on found that I wanted to do was better off with a different activity and xml layout

Comment: android:password="true" is deprecated

Answer (score 1):

Set the input type of your `Edittext` with `setInputType(TYPE_NUMBER_VARIATION_PASSWORD)`. More info [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html#TYPE_NUMBER_VARIATION_PASSWORD). It seems it's only available from Honeycomb

Answer (score 1):

In your xml

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/EditText01"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:password="true"
android:digits="1234567890" 
android:inputType="number"/>
```

the digits part makes it so you can't use symbols or any other characters, and this ensures that ONLY numbers will be entered. using the inputType="phone" method, parentheses and pound signs can still be entered