# How to get a pin number password keyboard in android?

Tags: android, passwords, numbers, android-edittext

I need a number keyboard on a PIN `EditText`. I tried using

```
android:inputType="number|textPassword"
```

This brings up the number keypad, but the characters are not password chars.

How to get a number keypad that shows password chars in `EditText` view?

The app runs on 2.2 and above.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2017674/edittext-set-for-password-with-phone-number-input-android/2017791#2017791

Comment: @NathanVillaescusa The accepted answer there did not help. That is not my requirement.. I used another answer that suggested setting the type programatically..

Answer (score 3):

You should have a look here:
[Edittext set for password with phone number input? (android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2017674/edittext-set-for-password-with-phone-number-input-android)

It states that 
`android:password` is deprecated, but is the only way because `android:inputType="phone|textPassword"` is ignored ...

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/EditText01"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:password="true"
    android:inputType="phone" 
/>
```

Answer (score 2):

In my styles.xml, these two seem to work for me:

```
<item name="android:inputType">numberPassword</item>
<item name="android:password">true</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
     <EditText
         android:id="@+id/pinEdit"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_margin="4dp"
         android:digits="1234567890"
         android:inputType="textPassword"
         android:maxLength="4" >

         <requestFocus />
     </EditText>
```

If digits will work for you.

EDIT: Ah, I see, it doesn't bring up the number keypad....back to the drawing board.

Comment: android:inputType="numberPassword" for numeric keyboard

Answer (score 0):

Use : "numberSigned|numberPassword"