# How to make android edittext action like password input when login wi-fi on android?

Tags: android

I want to create a  edittext which automatically hidden my input password text one by one when i input a password. 
now i'm using

```
inputPassword.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
```

with

```
inputPassword.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD);
```

but it effect for all of text in the edittext,which is not what i really need.
  help me please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use this method to do so `setTransformationMethod()`, i.e.

```
inputPassword.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD);
inputPassword.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
```

you can get more details [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTransformationMethod%28android.text.method.TransformationMethod%29)

Comment: i checked , it not works, this code work in the same of we set 'android:inputType="textPassword"'

Answer (score 2):

Add to your EditText in xml:

```
android:inputType="textPassword"
```

Comment: i have tried on your answer and all [link] and [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9892617/programmatically-change-input-type-of-the-edittext-from-password-to-normal-vic][http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2017674/edittext-set-for-password-with-phone-number-input-android] but this is not what i need